# In Bayesian inference, it is said that for large samples, the posterior density is dominated by the likelihood. What does this mean?

Tags: bayesian, inference, posterior

In Bayesian inference, it is said that
***for large samples, the posterior density is dominated by the likelihood. Furthermore, in the region where the likelihood is large, the posterior density is nearly constant.***
Could you kindly explain the logic behind such as a statement?
I would really appreciate if somebody could shed some light on this.